# Why does my sidebar move down to the bottom of the page rather than stay on the side?

Tags: html, css, drupal, view

I have a website with a blog and sidebar on the right hand side and it looks fine, however when I go onto page 2 of the blog, the sidebar moves down to the bottom of the page.

You can see what I mean by going to these links

http://www.beatinganger.com/blog (Sidebar looks normal)

http://www.beatinganger.com/blog?page=1 (Sidebar moves down to the bottom)

I have looked at the source code and I can see no changes in the difference between the 2 pages.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The difference is the right container div is placed inside the left container div of the page1. please check the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your #left_container element on the sub-page is not being closed and therefore the #right_container element is being contained inside it.

Comment: Thanks - now to try and find out how to fix it ;)

Answer (score 1):

The container div closing is causing a problem (as the other answers point out); also your div with the vertical_menu class is breaking out of its allotted size - which will probably cause float issues when your divs are closed:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Amelvin, will try and sort it out - not sure why it does that though becuase the CSS is the same, the only difference is that it is using Drupal Views.

Comment: the vertical_menu div is 300px wide - some of the elements inside are overflowing - the image I pulled above was using Google Chrome, which will let you fiddle with the size of elements without you having to rebuild the page.  Firebug in Firefox does the same.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, something is up with the template of the second URL, so that the sidebar is injected INSIDE the left 'main' column.

Answer (score 0):

the #right_container http://www.beatinganger.com/blog?page=1  is in the different hierarchy than the [enter link description here](http://www.beatinganger.com/blog). #right_container and #left_container should be in the same parent and level as shown in the first link.

Another advise though, I notice that the content of the #right_container has slightly "wider" content than the container itself. Make sure the content elements are smaller or equal to the width of the parent container, or set #right_container -> overflow: hidden; a quick hackish way though.